# Launch new terminal instance with zsh using custom prompt string

Tags: terminal, zsh, environment-variables, prompt, gnome-terminal

I want to be able to launch a terminal emulator (preferably gnome-terminal) with interactive zsh running inside using a custom prompt string. I don't want to modify my default prompt string in `.zshrc` because I use that most often and it is just occasionally I want to launch a terminal with a custom zsh prompt string (more specifically, I want the time to show up in the right hand side prompt).

If I already have a terminal window open, I can solve this by running:

```bsh
export RPS1=%T zsh
```

But I can't figure out the syntax for making this work together with launching a new terminal instance. This is what I have tried with the error message below each command:

```bsh
gnome-terminal -- export RPS1=%T zsh
# Error: Failed to execute child process “export” (No such file or directory)
```

```bsh
gnome-terminal -- sh -c export RPS1=%T zsh
# Prints all the options, like with `set`
# and then exits with "The child process
# exited normally with status 0".
```

```bsh
gnome-terminal -- sh -c "export RPS1=%T zsh"
# The child process exited normally with status 0.
```

```bsh
gnome-terminal -- sh -c "export RPS1=%T; zsh"
# This start the terminal with zsh, but the RSP1 is not changed
```

I considered reading a custom rc file, [like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36152028/2166823), but there does not seem to be a way of doing this in zsh without using `source`, which was giving me similar problems as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `zshrc`, allow for overriding `RPS1` by setting it as:

```bsh
# If rps1 is not set, use a default value
RPS1=${rps1-"Your usual RPROMPT"}
```

- Now you can launch a command with a different `RPS1` by setting `rps1` in its environment, for example:

```bsh
rps1=%T gnome-terminal
```

- The parameter expansion form `${param-word}` allows `RPS1` to be set to null:

```bsh
rps1= gnome-terminal
```

Parameters used by the shell (such as `RPS1`) needn't be exported. They are used to set up the shell, so should be set once in the rc file.

If a program (e.g. `gnome-terminal`) is launched with `rps1` in its environment, any subsequent programs launched from it will see `rps1` in their environment. To avoid this, either of the following could be added to `zshrc`: `unset rps1` (after using it to set `RPS1`) or `typeset +x rps1`.

---

*BTW*, the following will export two shell variables:

```bsh
export RPS1=%T zsh
```

- The above is `export` with two arguments, resulting in `RPS1=%T` & `zsh=''` being created in the environment
- To set `RPS1` in the current shell, simply do:

```
RPS1=%T
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not know about using a default variable value like that, neat! My `RPS1` is usually set by an extension via oh-my-zsh, so I have put the following line after sourcing oh-my-zsh in `.zshrc`: `RPS1=${custom_rps1-$RPS1}`. Then I can launch a new terminal with a custom prompt via `gnome-terminal -- sh -c 'custom_rps1="%T" zsh'`.

Comment: How is your answer different than the one I provided earlier?

Answer (score 2):

When you run the shell, it's processing your `/~.zshrc`, which is overwriting the prompt.

One option would be to do something like this in your `~/.zshrc`:

```bsh
MY_PROMPT="${MY_PROMPT:-"> "}" # Set the value to "> " if it isn't currently set
RPS1="${MY_PROMPT}"
```

Then, if you start a shell, you'll get:

```
> 
> MY_PROMPT="my new prompt > " zsh
my new prompt >
```

Note here that it's important that I chose a non-standard variable (here `MY_PROMPT`) since standard variables might already contain default values before the shell processes your `~/.zshrc`.